# C++: reference to a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, containers

I have this code (apologies for the debug stuff stuck in it)

```
PartialPage& DoubleTree::oldestPage()
{
    PartialPage& pageToKill = pageTree.begin()->second;
    long timeToKill = pageTree.begin()->second.getTime();
    map<long, PartialPage>::iterator itOld;
    cerr << "Page " << pageToKill.getPageNumber() << " with time " << timeToKill << endl;
    for (itOld = pageTree.begin(); itOld != pageTree.end(); itOld++) {
        cerr << itOld->first << " : " << itOld->second.getTime() << ",";
        if (itOld->second.getTime() < timeToKill) {
            timeToKill = itOld->second.getTime();
            pageToKill = itOld->second;
            cerr << endl << "Replaced with " << pageToKill.getPageNumber() << " with time " << timeToKill << endl;
        }
    }
    cerr << "Tree has " << pageTree.size() << " elements and we picked page " <<     pageToKill.getPageNumber() << endl;
    return pageToKill;
}
```

This code generates output like this:

```
Page 32788 with time 1411932643167898
32788 : 1411932643167898,32790 : 1411932640129861,
Replaced with 32788 with time 1411932640129861
32791 : 1411932640456679,32792 : 1411932643042340,32794 : 1411932640172263,32795 : 1411932640203512,32796 : 1411932640187651,32797 : 1411932640189676,32798 : 1411932640379028,32799 : 1411932640077458,
Replaced with 32788 with time 1411932640077458
32800 : 1411932639850996,
Replaced with 32788 with time 1411932639850996
32801 : 1411932641733754,32802 : 1411932640378079,32803 : 1411932640392161,32804 : 1411932640427125,32811 : 1411932639429403,
Replaced with 32788 with time 1411932639429403
32812 : 1411932639552400,32813 : 1411932640426173,32814 : 1411932639791659,32816 : 1411932640393999,32817 : 1411932643165226,32818 : 1411932640074872,32819 : 1411932640200932,32820 : 1411932640189102,32822 : 1411932640074734,32823 : 1411932643037665,32824 : 1411932641725923,32825 : 1411932639860631,32838 : 1411932643167861,32839 : 1411932643019133,32840 : 1411932639854076,32878 : 1411932640058203,32897 : 1411932639969865,32909 : 1411932639889327,32916 : 1411932640058292,32945 : 1411932640071503,32974 : 1411932639957135,32984 : 1411932639958741,32988 : 1411932639959924,32991 : 1411932639961069,32992 : 1411932639974983,32993 : 1411932639955969,33011 : 1411932639871191,33014 : 1411932639874551,33015 : 1411932639876698,33016 : 1411932639906830,33020 : 1411932639872242,33030 : 1411932640058627,33067 : 1411932640059679,33076 : 1411932640061764,33080 : 1411932640063085,33082 : 1411932640064271,33084 : 1411932640076206,33085 : 1411932640060746,33104 : 1411932643135052,33105 : 1411932643134970,33106 : 1411932640432242,33107 : 1411932640423850,33108 : 1411932640426904,33861 : 1411932643135173,33862 : 1411932640433903,33863 : 1411932643046850,33864 : 1411932643126930,33865 : 1411932641730018,37962 : 1411932643167875,38987 : 1411932643135268,38988 : 1411932643018577,38989 : 1411932641563440,38990 : 1411932641219821,38997 : 1411932640316266,40511 : 1411932643018354,40512 : 1411932639928912,40514 : 1411932643019102,40522 : 1411932640356638,41583 : 1411932643019015,41584 : 1411932640009668,41585 : 1411932640033429,41594 : 1411932642524801,41595 : 1411932643019820,41596 : 1411932643023008,41597 : 1411932642353290,41598 : 1411932642417264,41599 : 1411932642322596,41600 : 1411932643023238,41601 : 1411932642782395,41602 : 1411932641662080,41603 : 1411932642651784,41604 : 1411932642154134,41605 : 1411932643042188,41606 : 1411932641115901,41607 : 1411932641941591,41609 : 1411932641818136,41610 : 1411932642433396,41611 : 1411932642433411,41613 : 1411932642889449,41614 : 1411932642324828,41615 : 1411932641640108,41616 : 1411932642181100,41618 : 1411932641616281,41619 : 1411932641324974,41621 : 1411932642207235,41622 : 1411932643037599,41624 : 1411932642225616,41625 : 1411932642356076,41626 : 1411932642113908,41627 : 1411932642092238,41628 : 1411932641488112,41629 : 1411932641674993,41630 : 1411932641850897,41631 : 1411932641987161,41632 : 1411932642220932,41633 : 1411932642621807,41634 : 1411932643165195,41635 : 1411932641634666,41636 : 1411932641739212,41638 : 1411932643038514,41639 : 1411932643026740,41640 : 1411932642354417,41641 : 1411932640509806,41642 : 1411932640546388,41643 : 1411932640584662,41644 : 1411932640624924,41645 : 1411932640661431,41646 : 1411932640699992,41647 : 1411932640736103,41648 : 1411932640775231,41649 : 1411932640813379,41650 : 1411932640850822,41651 : 1411932640897932,41652 : 1411932640947271,41653 : 1411932640999481,41654 : 1411932641567729,41655 : 1411932643038330,43492 : 1411932641117114,43493 : 1411932640556557,43494 : 1411932640609545,43495 : 1411932640679172,43496 : 1411932640760872,43497 : 1411932640834402,43498 : 1411932641139833,43499 : 1411932643038068,43500 : 1411932640999450,43501 : 1411932641004273,43502 : 1411932641032261,43503 : 1411932641034647,33546237 : 1411932640172153,33546238 : 1411932643167893,33546239 : 1411932640284429,33546240 : 1411932639439851,33546241 : 1411932640431664,Tree has 150 elements and we picked page 32788
```

In other words, it correctly spots when an element in the `map` has an older time stamp, but does not seem to update the reference to refer to that instance.

What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but does not seem to update the reference to refer to that instance.

You cannot update references in C++.

When you write:

```
pageToKill = itOld->second;
```

You mutate the object which was bound to the reference `pageToKill` during its initialization.

If you want a "reference" that can be rebound, use a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
 PartialPage& pageToKill = pageTree.begin()->second;
```

and a few lines later,

```
        pageToKill = itOld->second;
```

The above line replaces the value of the what `pageToKill` references -- the first value in the map.

You could try:

```
map<long, PartialPage>::iterator pageToKillIter = pageTree.begin();
```

and later...

```
        pageToKillIter->second = itOld->second; // Replace the value of
                                                // what pageToKillIter points to.
        pageToKillIter = itOld; // Let pageToKillIter point to the new iterator
                                // location
```

Comment: @Galik, the line `cerr << endl << "Replaced with "...` made me think perhaps they wanted to.